# Vocabulary Processor function

Tags: python, tensorflow, text-classification

I am researching about embedding input for Convolution Neural Network and I understand Word2vec. However, in [CNN text classification](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf/blob/master/train.py). dennybritz used function `learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor`. In the [document](http://tflearn.org/data_utils/). They said it Maps documents to sequences of word ids. I am not quite sure how this function work. Does it creates a list of Ids then maps the Ids with Words or It has an dictionary of words and their Ids, when run function it only give the ids ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Lets say that you have just two documents `I like pizza` and `I like Pasta`. Your whole vocabulary consists of these words `(I, like, pizza, pasta)` For every word in the vocabulary, there is an index associated like so (1, 2, 3, 4). Now given a document like `I like pasta` it can be converted into a vector [1, 2, 4]. This is what the `learn.preprocessing.VocabularyProcessor` does. The parameter `max_document_length` makes sure that all the documents are represented by a vector of length `max_document_length` either by padding numbers if their length is shorter than `max_document_length` and clipping them if their length is greater than `max_document_length` Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks Kashyap, so It only encoding the document into vector space. Does it have a name in Natural Language Processing ?

Comment: @ngoduyvu As far as I know there is none... This is one of the pre-processing steps that is done in most of the natural language processing systems.

Comment: max_document_length should be the number of distinct words